# Best graphic library for .NET/Mono

Tags: .net, graphics, mono, cross-platform

I am looking for a high-performance graphic library for .NET and Mono. I have taken a look at [Tao framework](http://www.taoframework.com/) and, while it is very complete, it's quite lacking in terms of usability. It should be cross-platform compatible.

What other alternatives worked for you?

Comment: Looks like the Tao framework is offline these days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenGL would be my choice, .NET bindings exist from many open source wrappers, with OpenGL you're set for cross platform.

Answer (score 6):

There is a more modern OpenGL wrapper for .NET/Mono called OpenTK.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with mhutch - OpenTK is a very good .NET/Mono wrapper for OpenGL. For one, it has its own vector/matrix math library that, among other things, contains some of the more useful GLUT functions (I used to miss) like CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView and LookAt. I've found this library especially useful now that the matrix stack is no longer "kosher". Finally, it comes with a nice sample project so you can study how to use the wrapper without extensive documentation study.